# simulating Bluetooth connection in Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth, ios-frameworks

I made some changes to an iOS framework that establishes Bluetooth connection between iPhone devices so that they can exchange messages. Additionally, I have access to the source code of an app that uses this framework to allow its users to exchange messages using Bluetooth connection provided by this framework.

Now I need to test the framework by running the app in the Xcode simulator but not sure how to simulate Bluetooth connectivity in the simulator.
Is it possible to run the app in two simulators to test if they can exchange messages using Bluetooth capability provided by the framework?

I'm using Xcode 12.4 on macOS 10.15.4 Catalina, thanks!

Comment: The simulator does not support Bluetooth. You will need two physical devices or you would need to mock the Bluetooth connection and replace it with an IP connection (which is probably quite a lot of work).

Comment: that does seem like a lot of work!! Thank you Paulw11